# Google Play App publishing with two different developer names

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

I have published several Android applications for the Google Play Store through my Google account, but all under my company's developer name.

Now I want to publish an App under my name with the same user account, but this does not seem to be possible without changing the developer name for all previously published apps? Is it possible to publish Apps under more than one developer name with the same Google account?

The only solution I am seeing at the moment is generating another Google Account to use for my personal Apps, which seems quite silly, and I am hoping there is a better way.

Comment: Its not silly. You cant give two names to your organisation. So you have to create another account and upload your personall apps.

Comment: Is it maybe possible to move my currently published apps to a different account? I would rather have my personal google account for personal Apps and create a new account for the company.

Comment: Another use-case for this situation is a company with different names (translations) in different countries.

Comment: Although, I understand that position Ms Yvette I still would like to bring to your attention the description of the "publishing" tag:

"releasing software to users. This may include releasing compiled binaries on a hardware medium, for download, or permitting access to a non-development web service."

I find it quite unfair to claim this question as off-topic when such tags are allowed simultanously, it was in fact the reason why I felt comfortable posting this question on Stackoverflow in the first place.

Comment: This is a very valid question for a developer that manages apps for multiple brands.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If someone else is wondering I can indeed confirm that this does not seem possible (to have more than one developer name with the same account). If you are in my position you have two possibilities:

1. Make a new Google account and register as an [Android developer](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113468?hl=en) then use that account for your new Apps.
2. Make a new Google account and transfer existing Apps to it [via this link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/checklist/3294213).

Comment: Thanks for sharing. And yes I am also suprised that Yvette has closed this as off topic.

Comment: This is certainly not off-topic! Thanks for that insight!