# Shared ownership of app published on google play between different developers at once

Tags: android, google-play, publish

Me and 2 other friends have made an app, and we'd like to publish it on the Play store. However, I can't find anything relating to how I can give them credit too if I were to publish it under my developer account. How can I ensure that they are both included as developers for the app?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Play App publishing with two different developer names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20993195/google-play-app-publishing-with-two-different-developer-names)

Comment: I dont think its a duplicate... That link refers to someone wanting to transfer ownership from one account to another. This is asking to share ownership between people for one app.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a third-party vendor support question and not a programming question according to the [help] guidelines. If you have questions about allowable policies or your specific account at one of the app stores, contact that store and ask their support staff.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different forms of credit, and so it will depend on the relationship between you and your friends.

If it is just moral credit, you could easily add a credits page in your app, or put information about them in the app description.

However, often these things come down to ownership. Conceptually the developer account an app is published under represents the entity (company / organization / person) who owns the app. If you want it to be reflected that you all own the app, I'd recommend:

- create a new gmail address and a new developer account for things you do together called whatever you want to call the organization: eg "Me and My friends software".
- then in the Google Play console add [all of you as users with full permissions](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2528691)

That way it is very clear this app belongs to all of you. It also makes things easier if you want to found a legal company etc later.